# Error clone project gitlab with https

Tags: git, https, gitlab

I've a problem when i try to clone my Gitlab project with the protocol "Https". With the git protocol everything works fine.

The error:

```
Cloning into 'test'...
fatal: https://XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX/user.name/test.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

I've tried many solutions but the error is still here.

Somebody can help me?

Thank's for your help and have a nice day!

Comment: Which GitLab version are you running?

Comment: Same issue here. I have this on a fresh install of 4.2 as well as an upgrade install of 4.2.

Comment: are you trying to clone a new project?

Answer (score 2):

My Problem was the Apache configuration file. My example configuration

```
<VirtualHost ip:80>
  ServerName git.domain.tld
  Redirect permanent / https://git.domain.tld/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ip:443>
  ServerName git.domain.tld
  DocumentRoot /home/git/gitlab/public

  <Location />
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
    ProxyPassReverse http://git.domain.tld
  </Location>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]
  RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https'
</VirtualHost>
```

Source: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/web-server/apache

Answer (score 0):

A common source of this error is some sort of mistake in the URL. Be sure you have it right. Can you clone over HTTP? Is your server set up to serve the repository over both HTTP and HTTPS?

If your git client (read the output of `git --version`), it won’t be able to use the smart HTTP back end.

A comment in [GitLab issue #1924](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1924) suggests ruling out permission issues on the server side.

Comment: No the URL is right, but I can't clone over HTTP too. I checked the link you gave me but nothing in solve my problem.

Comment: git version is 1.8.1.msysgit.1.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when you've changed the default configuration for the `relative_url_root` variable for the gitlab application in your `.../gitlab/config/gitlab.yml` config file. The default value is `/`. When you change the default value to, e.g. `/gitlab`, the url will be

```
    http://your.domain/gitlab
```

This is showed as the cloning url for a project in the UI correctly, e.g.

```
    http://your.domain/gitlab/group/project.git
```

but somehow this configuration is not checked, while doing the actual clone over http or https.

There has already been a [discussion and a bugfix](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1228#issuecomment-14555439) about it in the gitlab issue list on github. Here is [the rawfile](https://github.com/atuleu/gitlabhq/blob/2e651605835e0363b506bdc5a83463c64b14abb5/lib/gitlab/backend/grack_auth.rb#L18).

My configuration is gitlab v5.0 and gitlab-shell v1.1.0.